# Change style of all elements using getElementsByTagName()

Tags: javascript, styles, visibility, getelementsbytagname

I'm fairly new to javascript and have been unable to get this code to work and I am unsure were and what I'm missing.

So here is what I want it to do. I'm trying to have the script read everything and switch the visibility of the span found in the body

```
<body> 
   <span hidden>A</span>     
   <span>X</span>
   <span hidden>B</span>
   <span>Y</span>
   <span hidden>C</span>
   <span>Z</span>
</body>
```

So instead of reading 'X Y Z' it will display 'A B C'

The code I have so far is..

```
$(function() {

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'visible') {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';    
        }
        else {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bKcCw/5/) of my code. I would greatly appropriate some feedback or possible threads that might point me in the right direction.

Comment: You spelled `visible` wrong in your jsFiddle, and you have too many `}` in your jsFiddle

Comment: and a misisng ; in his for loop.

Comment: sorry bout that copied over the wrong jsFiddle edit somehow. should be what I was working on now

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using the HTML5 `hidden` attribute, so you should just reverse that property.

```
for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].hidden = !elems[i].hidden;
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TEXJp/

---

If you were to use the `style` object, then you need to consider that it will only report styles that were set directly on the element. So your test should be for `== ""` instead of `== "visible"`, or for `== "hidden"` if you actually set it on the original elements.

```
<span style="visibility:hidden;">H</span>   
<span>V</span>

<span style="visibility:hidden;">H</span>
<span>V</span>
```

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if (elems[i].style.visibility === "hidden") {
        elems[i].style.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
        elems[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/TEXJp/1/

Comment: Thank You, that answered it perfectly. Was not expecting an answer so quickly. You even managed to grab the first jsFiddle before I noticed it was setup wrong. That must have been almost a minute after I posted.

Answer (score 2):

if fixed your code:

```
$(function () {


    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden') {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'visibile';
        } else {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

});
```

It was just a missing `;` and a `}` too much

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little bit and now it seems to work.

```
<body> 
   <span style="visibility: hidden;">A</span>     
   <span>X</span>
   <span style="visibility: hidden;">B</span>
   <span>Y</span>
   <span style="visibility: hidden;">C</span>
   <span>Z</span>
</body>
```

```
$(function() {

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

    for (var i = 0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].style.visibility == 'hidden') {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'visible';    
        }
        else {
            elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

});
```

The problem is that you are using the html attribute `hidden`, but you are modifying the css attribute `hidden`. I changed your HTML code to set hidden as a css property instead of a HTML property. Also, I switched your if else block and it worked. I think the style.visibility is not initialized until you give it a value. It equals `null`, not `visible`.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few syntax errors, including an unmatched curly brace, and a comma in your for loop definition instead of a semi-colon.

Also your html refers to the hidden attribute, yet your javascript is flipping the visibility via styles.

Here is a working fork. http://jsfiddle.net/yPU2T/1/

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].hidden = !elems[i].hidden;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You are using jquery, so no need to get elements the way you did it

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var elems = $('span.hidden');
    elems.hide();


})
```